# Polly exception not being caught

Tags: c#, .net, polly

Can someone please explain why the below code is failing on first attempt and throwing unhandled exception? Much appreciated.

```
using Polly;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestPolly
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Policy.Handle<DivideByZeroException>().Retry(10).Execute(() => DoSomething(0));
    }

    private static void DoSomething(int num)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Doing division");
        var y = 2 / num;
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Probable duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057939/ . See that question, and the detailed explanation of why this is a debugging artefact only, in the Polly wiki: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Debugging-with-Polly-in-Visual-Studio

Comment: Ok that makes sense now! Thanks for this. My googling let me down on this.

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/106

Answer (score 5):

You are just seeing the debugger break on the Exception, as [explained in detail in this article on the Polly wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Debugging-with-Polly-in-Visual-Studio).

> Can someone please explain why the below code is failing on first attempt 
>   and throwing unhandled exception?

The code is not failing nor throwing an unhandled exception.  When you press F5 (or click Continue in the debugger) to continue debugging, you will see execution continue - and that the exception *is* being handled by the policy.